# What's this 405 Method Not Allowed svn error?

Tags: svn, http-status-code-405

When trying to commit I get:

> 405 Method Not Allowed

In response to a MKACTIVITY request.

Comment: Where is the svn server and who set it up?

Comment: It's a google code repo.

Answer (score 3):

Similar issue resolved [by this user](https://serverfault.com/questions/11996/subversion-error-405-method-not-allowed-in-response-to-mkcol/133880#133880) should be a pointer

> I had a similar problem with
>   MKACTIVITY on googlecode. It was
>   because I had checked out the
>   repository with http:, but check-ins
>   required https:.

and the comment

> You either need to recheckout the
>   folder with https: (or if you're
>   sneaky clear out the folder except for
>   the .svn, then modify the contents of
>   .svn/entries which has the url from
>   http => https. Now the commit screen
>   would show the https URL

Comment: Would SVN's Relocate accomplish the same thing as the second part?